# Stack caprica jquery org chart vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [caprica's jquery org charg plugin](https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart) to create [interactive work breakdown structures](http://www.stakeholdermap.com/plan-project/plan-project-stage1.html).

I want to make the 3rd level organize vertically rather than horizontally [like this image](http://www.stakeholdermap.com/plan-project/finding-a-job-work-breakdown-structure.html)

I am using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/decker2/0h48e1g4/2/

I think I need to change this code, but keep messing up the table

```
        // Make this node...
    var $nodeRow = $("<tr/>").addClass("nodes");
    var $nodeCell = $("<td/>").addClass("node").attr("colspan", 2);
    var $childNodes = $node.children("ul:first").children("li");
    if ($childNodes.length > 1) {
        $nodeCell.attr("colspan", $childNodes.length*2);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why is there preformatted code in your HTML?

Comment: The Caprica org chart plugin uses jquery to turn a list into a html table. This is great, but a nested li (a node with lots of children can mean the chart gets very wide) I want to stack the 3rd level like the image.

Comment: removed preformatted code and updated jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you ever got this nodes vertical for level 3